# Where on Earth can you find plasma?

Tags: earth, plasma-physics, states-of-matter

Ok, so not that 'where on earth', like literally - 'Where on Earth'.

Where on Earth, can you find matter in the 4th state, i.e. the plasma state?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)#Common_plasmas

Comment: *Not* the blood bank (unless they happen to have a neon sign).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Plasmas are a common part of the world we live in.  The definition of plasma allows them to exist within an environment consisting mostly of bound atoms.

A variety of human technology creates plasmas. The type I hear plasma researchers reference most is a simple RF Plasma. This is perhaps the most direct way to use electricity to shake off the electrons from their atoms within a confined volume by using fast oscillating electromagnetic fields.

Nature also creates plasma.  An [Aurora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora_%28astronomy%29) is certainly included.  Many less "exotic" plasma states are much more common.  A fire has a low population of the ionized species, but is still a plasma.  From the Wikipedia plasma article:

[image: types of plasmas]

Answer (score 6):

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_plasma_(physics)_articles) for a list of available plasmas over there..! Or have a look below for the chart which shows variation of temperature and electron density in different plasmas..!

[image: Plasmas]

A quick **Googling** would've provided the answer. Common examples include

- Lightning..!
- The Sun (from Core to Corona)
- Fluorescent Lights and Neon Signs
- Nebulae (Luminous Clouds in Space)
- The Solar Wind
- Primordial Fusion during the evolution of the Universe
- Magnetic Confinement Fusion Plasmas
- Inertially Confined Fusion Plasmas
- Flames as Plasmas
- Auroras (Northern & Southern Lights)
- Interstellar Space (It's not empty... It's a plasma)
- Quasars, Radiogalaxies, and Galaxies (Emit plasma radiation and microwaves)
- Large Scale Structures of Galaxies (Filamentary and magnetized..!)
- Dense Solid State Matter (When shocked by nuclear explosion or earthquakes which emit both visible light and radio waves)

Answer (score 5):

Naturally ? Probably lightning

Answer (score 1):

Lightning, Arcing (Between electrodes or in high voltage power line), The every CFL lamp that you see around, Plasma TV, Halogen Lightning. Aurora, and I am sure i am missing few others.

Answer (score 1):

Best example of plasma on earth is lightning. It's, natural. plasma exists at high temperatures. Those temperatures don't usually exist here. But, they do for a brief second in a bolt of lightning

- Sun
- Solar wind
- Auroras
- Nebulae
- Fluorescent lights
- Neon signs

Answer (score -3):

Electric is a type of plasma.Lightning is electric.Lamps and bulbs are lighten up by electric.All are plasmas

Comment: It is very unclear what you talk about. Please expand or at least clarify.

Comment: There is, perhaps, room for this to be correct if you are talking about the free electron gas in the conduction band of typical wires, but on a gross scale this is simply wrong. Needs to be either much more explicit or deleted.